# grep: Syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: shell, grep, quoting

I have this problem: I'm looking for a string inside file .
Syntax is:

```
grep -E ‘( ^ |  [[:space:]] )[A-Z]{2}[[:digit:]]{2}((- | [[:space:]] )[[:alnum:]]{4}) {3} ’  (filename)
```

When I run this command inside ubuntu I get this error:

```
Syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Why?

Comment: For me the command works. Which shell do you use?

Comment: it look like a copy/paste from a word-like document, quotes, double quotes are often turn to a fancier quote, but no longer work in linux.

Comment: Be careful with the spaces inside regexps...

Comment: grep -E ‘( ^ |  [[:space:]] )[A-Z]{2}[[:digit:]]{2}((- | [[:space:]] )[[:alnum:]]{4}) {3} ’  (filename) run correctly: it was a stupid character question. But now I have an error grep: memory exhausted when I try to run this statement inside a dd file (very big file). Do You have some indications about this ?

Comment: Either the shell, or whatever you're copy-and-paste'ing from, are mangling your quotes or whitespace. Try typing the command afresh, rather than copy-and-paste. If you're running it from inside a (shell-)script, then whichever shell that's running could be mangling the command; turn on verbosity and execute shell-options to see what's literally getting onto the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sounds like you're not using proper simple quote (`'`). Try to copy and paste this one:

```
grep -E '( ^ | [[:space:]] )[A-Z]{2}[[:digit:]]{2}((- | [[:space:]] )[[:alnum:]]{4}) {3} '
```

(I have the same error in bash if I copy and paste your  script, which use `’` instead of `'`)

Comment: Thanks: it run correctly BUT I have a new problem. I have a dd file that is very big. When I run this statement I have an error: grep: memory exhausted.  Have You some indications for this problem ?

Comment: Hi, `dd` is for Disk Dumps, thus contains binary data. It's unlikely you have to grep such a file... If you really want to, you may try to find only characters strings in that file then grep them: `strings file.dd | grep ...` If your file is actually only text, you may split it in several smaller files, for instance: `split -n 500000 file.dd` (`man split`) then grep the generated files (which are by default `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, ...)